# To upgrade mysql vesion in workbench

Tags: mysql, version, mysql-workbench

I am using latest version of workbench The available MySQL version is 5.0.27. Does anybody knows how to update MySQL version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL Workbench is a client tool that uses an existing server. Both have their own version numbers. The current GA (generally available) version of MySQL Workbench is 6.2.5. For the server there are obviously different versions. You don't need to consider WB when upgrading. Just upgrade your server and WB will happily work with it.

## Update

Meanwhile the MySQL group switched to a unique versioning scheme, where all products have the same version number, to indicate which release of a tool works best with which server (e.g. MEB 8.0.15 with MySQL 8.0.15 or MySQL Workbench 8.0.16 with the same versioned server). It makes sense to update all components at the same time to ensure maximum compatibility.